# Control the Toolbar icon with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, icons, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm currently using within my app the **`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`** and **`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`**. Everything is working right, but there is a slight thing I want to change its behaviour.

When I open the drawer, the whole drawer occupies the `space of the Toolbar`. It would be nice that the Toolbar stays on top, like in the **`Google Music app`**. How can I achieve that?

But the most important thing isn't the previous. `At first, the icon which is loaded in the application is the three stripped one`. I've realised that after opening the drawer, the icon changes to an arrow. And after loading a fragment, the arrow remains there as the Toolbar icon, even if I press back until the first screen. How could I avoid the arrow appearing from after opening the drawer? I'd want to change this icon manually, specially when I load lower level fragments.

Thanks for your help!

Code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity {



...

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ListView mDrawerRightList;
    private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;
    private String[] mDrawerMenuTitles;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_options);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.theDrawerRelativeLayout);

        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerRightList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theDrawerRight);
        mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, mDrawerRightList);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theDrawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), 
                R.layout.drawer_list_item,
                mDrawerMenuTitles
        ));

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        setmToolbar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, 
                mDrawer,
                mToolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Configuración");
            }           

        };

        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        setToolbarSubtitle(getString(R.string.misrutas_titulo));

        initialisePreferences(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            replaceFragment(DEFAULT_FRAGMENT);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

     private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //selectItem(position);
            final int thePos = position;
            mDrawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                ....
                }
            });

            if(mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
                mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

     @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        setToolbarSubtitle(getString(R.string.app_name_subtitle));
      if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){
        finish();
      }
      else {
        super.onBackPressed();
      }
    }

    private void replaceFragment (String to){

        if(!to.equalsIgnoreCase(CURRENT_FRAGMENT)){
            CURRENT_FRAGMENT = to;
            Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(HomeActivity.this, to);
            String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
            String fragmentTag = backStateName;

            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

            if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
                FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                ft.commit();
            } 

        }

    }

    //More methods
    ....

}
```

**EDIT:**

I have been able to modify a little bit my layout, so that the Toolbar stays on top of the rest screen (drawer and fragment). But I haven't been able to control the icon. When I open the drawer, the hamburger icon converts into the arrow. When I close the drawer, the arrow is converted into the hamburger. But when I press an option within the drawer, a new fragment is inflated and the hamburger icon is replaced by the arrow until the application is closed, so that the hamburger icon is never seen.

How can I adapt the icon behaviour so that it doesn't change from hamburger to arrow when I click over a drawer option?

Answer (score 0):

now I try to do a similiar navigation drawer as you... 
Basically respect me is that I had a diferent package for navigation drawer that I think so is different from your navigation drawer... My package is:

```
 //From android studio
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

I don't know if this can help you, but I follow this greatest tutorial and my navigation drawer work it's similar as you wish!

http://androideity.com/2013/12/16/android-navigation-drawer-parte-1/
http://androideity.com/2014/02/26/android-navigation-drawer-parte-2/

I wait that I help you! Good luck!

PD: If you have a problems with this tutorial or same advice me! :D

Comment: I see your point, but the library is used in that example is the v4 ActionBar, and currently I'm using the new v7, which contains the brand-new Toolbar. Anyway, I'll follow this guide to adapt something.

Comment: Yes I use my customActionBar with this guide, thanks for your point and good luck!

Comment: Consider upgrading your app using the new Toolbar and the new v7 library :)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance seems that you are setting new drawer listener whenever item is selected, precisely in this snippet:

```
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //selectItem(position);
            final int thePos = position;
            mDrawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                ....
                }
            });

            if(mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
                mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerRelativeLayout);

        }
    }
```

This snippet replaces `ActionBarDrawerToggle` (which implements `DrawerListener` as well), so no calls are made to ActionBarDrawerToggle which controls the icon.

`How can I adapt the icon behaviour so that it doesn't change from hamburger to arrow when I click over a drawer option?`

Relating to your previous statements, this sound vague to me. Why you'd be preventing this default behaviour? You can prevent morphing by not calling super calls in `DrawerListener`'s methods.

Comment: By saying "preventing its default behaviour" what I mean is to, if clicking on an option that simply loads a new fragment, preventing the hamburger icon to be replaced by an arrow, more exactly, only replacing the arrow when a new activity is started. Have I explained myself correctly now?